# Updating variable type in mongodb compass & generating automatic auto-increment id type integer not object in mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to change the automatic _id generated by mongodb, then I got this error. I don't know which error he's mentionning here. Someone can help please?

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbFg.png)

I've already trying to create a user_id with auto increment in the schema model but it doesn't word. Also, I HAVE already use mongoose-sequence but another error is appearing like "Auto increment field already present and not of type "Number"".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to upload the error image